# Refactoring in Android Programming

Tags: android

Please, if someone could write the meaning of refactoring in android, how it is done and what is its use in android programming. I am using Eclipse.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Refactoring* means making small changes to improve the structure of a program without affecting its operation. So, for example, renaming a method or moving a method from a subclass to a superclass would be examples of small refactorings. Eclipse has a "Refactoring" context menu which automates these and a number of other simple refactorings.

This really has nothing to do with Android, though; it's just a general programming term. There's nothing about refactoring in Android programming that differs from any other system.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the refactoring option in Eclipse to rename my package and automatically rename folders and package references, and found it quite useful!  I didn't really know what refactoring meant in this case, until I decided to try it out while playing around with different menu options.

I have had many troubles in the past when I manually tried to change a package name or copy one package to a new one but with a different name, so the refactoring option comes in handy if you want to do it all in one fell swoop.